# How to plot variability/attribute gauge plot like in JMP using python code?

Tags: python-3.x

I tried to using Seaborn to generate some plots for statistical analysis. I use JMP as well but JSL is something I do not like, so I am trying to mimic the JMP's ability to plot by using Python.

One question I have that I haven't found good answers yet is how to plot variability/attribute gauge plot. In a simple word, the plot has multiple x-axes which cover different categories and they overlap each other to some degree. I will attach an plot here.

[image: Image of plot]]